# Is there any difference between user units and pixels?

Tags: html, svg

I've been reading several articles about SVG that make a clear distinction between using and not using units (this last case even has a name of its own), e.g.

> ```
> <!-- the viewport will be 800px by 600px -->
> <svg width="800" height="600">
>     <!-- SVG content drawn onto the SVG canvas -->
> </svg>
> ```
>
> In SVG, values can be set with or without a unit identifier. A
>   unitless value is said to be specified in user space using user units.
>   **If a value is specified in user units, then the value is assumed to be
>   equivalent to the same number of “px” units.** This means that the
>   viewport in the above example will be rendered as a 800px by 600px
>   viewport.
>
> You can also specify values using units. The supported length unit
>   identifiers in SVG are: em, ex, px, pt, pc, cm, mm, in, and
>   percentages.

<sup>[source](http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)</sup>

1. Is there any actual difference between omiting the unit and setting it to `px`?
2. Can I just set e.g. `mm` everywhere to avoid ambiguity, or I'll eventually be getting different results?

   ```
   <svg width="800mm" height="600mm">
   ```

Comment: 1. not for attributes, for CSS though you must supply units, 2. mm and px are different. Not sure I understand that question.

Comment: @RobertLongson 1.- Then is it the same than `<table width="100">` vs `<table style="width: 100px;">`? 2.- I want to know whether defining my figure in millimetres will put me intro trouble when trying to set the viewbox size in the browser, since that "user space" in pixels appears to be so relevant.

Comment: 1. table is not an SVG element. SVG rules about units do not apply to table elements. 2. depends what you're doing, some elements such as paths cannot take units, other elements can.

Comment: @RobertLongson What are the SVG rules then? Why make a distinction if `<svg width="800mm" height="600mm">` is invalid anyway? (It's invalid, isn't it?)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/coords.html#Units

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the link and for your time. The W3C explanation is clearer than most articles, but it's still terribly obscure. I apparently lack some background the reader is assumed to have. I think I've made a mistake trying to generate SVG with a server-side language for my current project—I'd better switch to a client-side JavaScript library that takes care of the internals.

Comment: Note that the svg element markup that you have in your comment above with units in mm is perfectly valid.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've taken a deep breath and I've decided to give up on understanding viewports, but I'll use SVG in my current project anyway. The rest of the features (shapes, paths, filters...) are very intuitive and everything works fine when you assign a fixed size to the canvas. I can do without scaling, which apparently in the sole feature that makes SVG a mess.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12788422.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: what follows is pure guessing (I only learnt the basics of SVG last week) but I'm sharing it because I believe it could help others with my same doubts and I hope it doesn't contain serious errors.</sup>

The SVG canvas is basically a mental concept—a infinite plane where you use Cartesian coordinates to place stuff and move around. It isn't too different from stroking shapes in a sheet of graph paper where you've drawn a cross to identify an arbitrary point as coordinate origin, except that notebooks are not infinite. In the same way that tou draw a 3-square radius circle in the sheet and you don't care that those squares represent 12 mm, you draw shapes in your SVG canvas using unitless dimensions because it doesn't really matter what exact physical size they represent. The SVG spec uses the term "user units" to express this idea.

Using actual units only makes sense in two situations:

1. When our virtual user units need to interact with real world, e.g., the canvas is to be printed in a computer monitor.
2. When we want an element in our graph to be defined in such a way that it doesn't scale, neither up nor down, e.g. a stroke around a letter that needs to look identical no matter how we resize the logo it belongs to.

It's in this situation, more specifically #1, when the px equivalence comes in handy. When we need to render the graph or make calculations what involve actual units, unitless dimensions are interpreted as pixels. We can think of it as a default because we can render the canvas any size and, in any case, pixels are no longer physical pixels in these days of high-res displays and builtin zoom.

And, for all this, it's probably better to just omit units in your SVG code. Adding them in a general basis only makes code unnecessarily verbose.