# How to get the pixel coordinates from a SVG path String

Tags: javascript, svg, gojs

I want to display geometric objects on a map using go.js in combination with leaflet.js
It is important for me that the geometric object sticks to their geo-position. I simply translate the pixel coordinates to lat/lng geo-coordinates.

However, for some geometric objects it is not that easy for me to get all the necessary geo-coordinates.
For a polygon I get an SVG-Path String like :

```
"F M54 77 L39 128 L0 146 L18 178 L45 215 L87 220 L79 321 L79 400 L153 371 L246 340 L296 325 L332 255 L324 207 L355 164 L338 138 L368 105 L380 23 L336 0 L282 35 L222 10 L147 10 L95 38 L60 44z"
```

as well as the pixel coordinates of the middle Point. [image: This is the polygon using the SVG-Path from above]

So I would need the pixel coordinate of every corner point.
Do you have any idea or suggestion how I could translate the SVG path to its pixel coordinates?

Hope you guys can help me.

Best regards!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XJN8.png)

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788422/svg-coordinate-system-points-vs-pixels) link? Maybe this can help you to find correlation between SVG coordinates points and pixels

Comment: The Path you provided is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a GoJS [`Part`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html) (or [`Node`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html)) that holds a `Shape` whose [`Shape.geometryString`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Shape.html#geometryString) is what you posted?

If so, I suggest that you look at the `Shape.geometry` and look at its [`Geometry.figures`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Geometry.html#figures)' [`PathFigure`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/PathFigure.html)s and their [`PathSegment`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/PathSegment.html)s.  For each of those points you can convert to GoJS document coordinates by adding the `Part.position` plus half the `Shape.strokeWidth`.  Then you can convert document coordinates to LatLng by calling Leaflet map's `containerPointToLatLng` method.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds good, but I am not sure how to get the shape object and its geometry.
diagram.findNodeForData(e).geometry is undefined.

How do I get the Shape.geometry?

Comment: Did `diagram.findNodeForData` return a Node rather than null?  If so, then you need to find the Shape that is inside the Node that is holding the Geometry that you are interested in.  That depends on how the template was defined.  It might be the only object in the Node, in which case it's just `node.elt(0)`.